# Can you set pointer to derived class after you set some values in the base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

I am new to c++ (I am using visual studio 2013) and I started experimenting with classes and inheritance. So I came up with a question which I can not find any anwser. Lets say we have this class:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class base{
protected:
     int var;
public:
     void setvalue(int);
     virtual void print();
};
class first:public base{
public:
    void print();
};
class second: public base{
public:
    void print();
};
```

Is there a way I can declare in my main() a pointer to base, set the value and **after** that choose if it is a first or second class? Ex:

```
int main(){
base *ptr = new base;
ptr->setvalue(1);
/* Here I choose if base is pointing to First or Second class*/
ptr->print(); // use the correct member, based on which class I choosed
return 0;}
```

Is this somehow possible? (As I said I am new to c++ so in case you have any questions, feel free to ask!)
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's not possible, the only thing that comes to mind is that you solve your problem in another way, perhaps using some well common *design pattern*.

In this case, given the little information you gave, [Factory pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) seems appropriate.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class base {
protected:
     int var;
public:
     void setvalue(int);
     virtual void print();
     static base* makeObject(int);
};

class first : public base {
public:
    void print();
};

class second : public base {
public:
    void print();
};

base* base::makeObject(int param) {
    base* ret = NULL;
    if(/* some condition based on params */) {
        ret = new first();
        ret->setvalue(0);
    } else if(/* some other condition */) {
        ret = new second();
        ret->setvalue(1);
    }
    return ret;
}

int main() {
    base *ptr = base::makeObject(...);
    base->print(); // use the correct member, based on which class I choosed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely. In my answer I used the strategy pattern, but in any case, a look at design patterns will give some ideas.

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! I am new to c++ and I've never seen again the static keyword or heard about the "factory method" but I get the general concept. So basically I can't do that and have to find a workaround. This "factory method" looks really nice and I think it could solve my problem. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

The type of an object is fixed at construction and can never be changed. So the direct answer to your question is "no".

But within that framework you have a lot of power. For example, you could separate your three classes out into four: three that do just do printing (BasePrinter, DerivedPrinter1, DerivedPrinter2) and other that just holds the value and doesn't have any virtual methods. Your BasePrinter class could get passed a ValueHolder object (by const reference) every time you call the print() method. Alternatively, each ValueHolder could have a pointer to BasePrinter object and pass in all the necessary data each time, with a little (non-virtual) print() method to do all this forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

You have to choose type at the creation of the object:

```
int main()
{
    base *ptr = new first; // here.
    ptr->setvalue(1);
    ptr->print(); // use first::print.
    delete ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not directly.  When you create an object, you need to specify its full type so that C++ knows how to correctly lay out memory for you.

If you actually need to change it later, you can always create a new class (of the correct derived type) and use the original base class to initialize it, then delete the original.  This might be slightly slower than the method you were proposing (depending on the final complexity of the class), but it would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using inheritance , it is best practice to define virtual destructor in your base class. It will take care proper clean up when you define complicated class.

```
int main(){
base *ptr = new base;
base->setvalue(1);
/* Here I choose if base is pointing to First or Second class*/
base->print(); // use the correct member, based on which class I choosed
return 0;}
```

What you are trying to do is not possible. You have to change your program as follows to avoid compilation error.

```
base *ptr = new base;
ptr->setvalue(1);
ptr->print(); 
delete ptr;
return 0;
```

Because you base pointer ptr always have the dynamic type of class base. this code always invoke `base::print` function

If you define ptr as follows, you can utilize the polymorphism.

```
  base * ptr = new first;
  ptr->setvalue(1);
  ptr-> print() 
  delete ptr
```

Here ptr has a dynamic type of class first and it will call function `first::print()`